# Cannot deploy spring boot application with docker to aws elastic beanstalk with eb cli using docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ebcli

I have a problem here!
I cannot deploy spring boot application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with eb cli using docker-compose.yml

Here my code!

Here my simple API

```
@RestController
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class TestApi {

private String activeProfile;

@GetMapping
public Map<String, String> isWorking() {
    return Map.of(
            "WORKING", "true"
    );
}

@GetMapping("active/profile")
public Map<String, String> showActiveProfile() {
    return Map.of(
            "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", activeProfile
    );
}

public String getActiveProfile() {
    return activeProfile;
}

public void setActiveProfile(String activeProfile) {
    this.activeProfile = activeProfile;
}
```

}

And here my Dockerfile

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17
ARG JAR_FILE=target/docker-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

And docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  spring-boot-prod-docker-app:
    image: beksultancs/docker-app:2.0
#    build:
#      context: ./
#      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod"
```

I've 2 spring boot active profile

1. DEFAULT
   inside default active profile

> ```
>  test.active_profile=DEFAULT
> ```

here only one line of code

2. PROD
   inside application-prod.yml

> ```
>  test.active_profile=PRODUCTION
>  server.port=5000
> ```

only two line

and when I tried deploy an application

with eb cli

> ```
>    $ eb init 
>    $ eb create
> ```

and here RESULT

```
2022-05-07 07:14:29    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2022-05-07 07:14:33    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2022-05-07 07:14:40    ERROR   Instance deployment failed to build the Docker image. The deployment failed.
2022-05-07 07:14:40    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2022-05-07 07:14:43    ERROR   [Instance: i-02fcf8292017f9e2e] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2022-05-07 07:14:43    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2022-05-07 07:14:43    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-02fcf8292017f9e2e'. Aborting the operation.
2022-05-07 07:14:44    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

> Instance deployment failed to build the Docker image

cannot solve this problem?
how I can deploy my application?

If you know another way to deploy spring boot application please leave a link to learn it or you can leave steps what to do?

thanks in advance!

Comment: "*`Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.`*" - Please [edit] the post and show the (relevant) log entries.

Comment: I'm sorry, Unfortunately I cannot fin it.